# Add keyboard done button using global function

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out how I can create a global function that adds a done button to keyboards I choose.

I can add a done button, but I currently copy the code to each view controllor. I want to add a function to the UITextField to show the done button on the keyboard.
Current code commonly found on stack overflow.

Code found in viewDidLoad:

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.sizeToFit()
let doneBotton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneClicked))

toolbar.setItems([doneBotton], animated: false)
```

@objc found outside viewdidload:

```
@objc func doneClicked() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could simply create an extension of UITextField like below:-

```
extension UITextField {

func addDoneButton() {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneClicked))

    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

    self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

@objc func doneClicked() {
    self.endEditing(true)
}
}
```

And call it like below:-

```
class DoneKeyboardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    txtField.addDoneButton()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this extension of `UITextField`.

the UITextField's extension is global, the `TextFieldDone protocol` is used for tagging where you add keyboards you choose.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, TextFieldDone {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        textField.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(self)
    }

    @objc
    func doneButtonAction(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("this")
    }
}

protocol TextFieldDone{
    func doneButtonAction(_ textField: UITextField)
}

extension UITextField: TextFieldDone{

    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(_ target: UIViewController)
    {
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackTranslucent
        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: target, action: #selector(doneButtonAction(_:)))

        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        items.append(flexSpace)
        items.append(done)
        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
        inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }

    @objc func doneButtonAction(_ textField: UITextField){
        print("PlaceHolder")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new view controller class that implements this functionality, then use it as a super class for the rest of your view controllers

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `UIViewController` and override its `viewDidLoad` with the implementation you've presented and then set all of your view controller classes in interface builder to your derived class instead of `UIViewController`.

Or you could subclass `UITextField` and set its keyboard to the Done keyboard as a default in its init method with:

```
class TextField : UITextField {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.returnKeyType = .done
    }
}
```

Then everywhere in your storyboards where you have a text field that you want to show the done button, you set the text field's class to `TextField` instead of `UITextField`. You need the initWithCoder because that's the initializer that gets called when creating the class from a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addDoneButtonOnKeyboardToInput()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addDoneButtonOnKeyboardToInput()
    }
    var doneToolbar: UIToolbar?
    var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem?
    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboardToInput() {
        if (doneToolbar == nil) {
            doneToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
            doneToolbar?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

            let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: SF.buttons.done, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: nil, action: #selector(doneButtonAction(sender:)))

            var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
            items.append(flexSpace)
            if let btn = doneButton {
                items.append(btn)
            }

            doneToolbar?.items = items
        }
        doneButton?.target = self
        doneToolbar?.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar

    }

    @objc
    func doneButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```